# Converting macros sequence to templated one

Tags: c++, templates, hook

I have following sequence of functions with marcos to setup hook in detours.

```cpp
SETUP_ORIG_FUNC(string_copy_n);
char* __cdecl HOOK(string_copy_n)(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size)
{
  if (src && dst && size && !convert_ulong_lock && Config::Setting::enable_translation) {
    auto tstr = Dictionary::GetSingleton()->Get(src);
    if (tstr) {
      return ORIGINAL(string_copy_n)(dst, tstr.value().c_str(), tstr.value().size());
    }
  }
  return ORIGINAL(string_copy_n)(dst, src, size);
}
```

Marcoses and typedef:

```cpp
#define SETUP_ORIG_FUNC(fn_name) fn_name fn_name##_orig = (fn_name)(module_handle + Config::Offset::fn_name);
#define HOOK(fn_name) fn_name##_hook
#define ORIGINAL(fn_name) fn_name##_orig

typedef char*(__cdecl* string_copy_n)(char* dst, const char* src, size_t size);
```

`Config::Offset::string_copy_n` stores offset of specific function

How can I implement all this with templates? Myabe there is more efficient and compact way?

I tried different templates with Ret and ...Args or just typedef as input, but always had invalid code. This is my best try:

```cpp
template <uintptr_t offset, typename Ret, typename ...Args>
Ret Original(Args&&... args)   {
    return (Ret)(module_handle + offset)(args...);
}
```

Comment: Provide how you potentially should use your rewritten function as well. It's unclear where to apply templates to this and what are you trying to achieve with it. Is `string_copy_n` is typename or a function name?

Comment: string_copy_n - typedef as i posted in original message.
In most ideal case i want to had i want to just only hook function, inside that i can call original one...
In other scenario i think about Hook sctructure template for storing hook and original or a HookManager class to manipulate all the stuff.

Comment: It is not a cast to `Ret` which is needed, but to correct function pointer (so depending of `Args&&...` is risky (const/value-reference type difference). It would be something like `return reinterpret_cast<Ret(*)(Args&&...)>(module_handle + offset)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`